# How to remove vim swap file warning

Tags: vim

After typed `vim ~/.ssh/config` in terminal, then got error message like picture1

[image: picture1]


**what I did for solving**

1.push D in the screen to try to delete swap file.but it looks like pointless

2.push r in the screen to confirm swap file.But I don't know how can I delete them.you can the condition in picture2.

[image: picture2]
please give me the tip how can I remove the error,

Comment: Use `rm` to delete the swap file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the swap file as suggested

`rm /Users/snowman/.ssh/.config.swp`

in case you edited the file using a different user (so you have no permission to delete the file) try

`sudo rm /Users/snowman/.ssh/.config.swp`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rm` as suggested by others including the answer from @Arsenio.
As you have multiple have files, you need to delete them one by one, of course
after recovering from the copy that you want.

```
\rm ~snowman/.ssh/.config.sw*
```

But newer version of `vim`, It is easier than `rm` and you already have newer version of `vim` which supports that[image].

New version of vim will have `(D)elete it` option. So you can

```
(R)ecover
```

followed by

```
:e!
```

At this point, we will have the same screen with `(D)elete it`. Now you can safely press <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
vim -r filename
```

and then there will be an option to delete the swap file.